# Learning camera OpenGl ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to understand how camera works on OpenGL ES, so I am tryng to look at the same point with the two differents types, `Matrix.frustumM` and `Matrix.orthoM`

I will like to know what exactly I am doing when use Matrix.frustumM or orthoM, I know that I apply them to the ProjectionMatrix but I dont understand what defines the parameters(left,right,bottom,top,near,far of what? it is supposed to be the screen of the phone? ) same with orthoM

I want to draw a square on the screen on 0,0,0 with 1f of height and weight(like 2D just to test the cameras)

but if I do onSurfaceCreated

```
    final float eyeX = 2f;
    final float eyeY = 5f;
    final float eyeZ = 8f;

    final float lookX = 2f;
    final float lookY = 5f;
    final float lookZ = 0.0f;

    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

onSurfaceChanged

```
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

            // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the
            // same
            // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
            final float ratio = (float) width / height;
            final float left = -ratio;
            final float right = ratio;
            final float bottom = -1.0f;
            final float top = 1.0f;
            final float near = 1.0f;
            final float far = 25.0f;


            Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
```

That is what i saw onn phone [image]

Draw function:

```
public void dibujarBackground()
{
    // Draw a plane

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBackgroundDataHandle);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f,2.0f, 0.0f);
    drawBackground();
}

private void drawBackground()
{
    coordinate.drawBackground(mPositionHandle, mNormalHandle, mTextureCoordinateHandle);

    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the
    // result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);


    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniform3f(mLightPosHandle,Light.mLightPosInEyeSpace[0], Light.mLightPosInEyeSpace[1], Light.mLightPosInEyeSpace[2]);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Coords of the square:

```
final float[] backgroundPositionData = {
        // In OpenGL counter-clockwise winding is default. 

 0f,  1f, 0.0f,
 0f,  0f,  0.0f,
1f,  1f, 0.0f, 
 0f,  0f,  0.0f, 
1f,  0f,  0.0f,
1f,  1f, 0.0f,

};

final float[] backgroundNormalData = {

0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, };

final float[] backgroundTextureCoordinateData = {
0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 
1.0f, 0.0f, };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall what you get in the end is a single matrix which is used to multiply the positions so that the visible fragments are in range [-1,1] in all 3 dimensions. That means if you use no matrix or use the identity the coordinates will need to be in this range to be visible. So the 3 matrix computations you are using are actually only conveniences to help you achieve a correct transformation:

- Ortho is an orthographical transformation. This means the visual representation of `x` and `y` screen coordinates are not effected by the `z` coordinate at all. Visually that means the object does not appear smaller when it is further. The values you insert into this convenience method are border values (left, right, top, bottom) which means a rectangle with same coordinates will take exactly the full screen. These values are mostly used to be the same as your view coordinate system (left = 0, right = screenWidth, top = 0, bottom = screenHeight). Also there are near and far parameters which represent the clipping planes so that positions smaller then near or further then far are not visible. This projection is mostly used for 2D drawing.
- Frustum matrix is designed so that the `x` and `y` coordinates are reduced with increasing `z`. This means an object will appear smaller when further. The border parameters are connected to the `near` parameter so that the rectangle with border coordinates having `z` at near will appear as full screen. The `near` must be larger then zero in this case or the result is unpredictable. The `far` promoter is just a clipping plane but same as with `ortho` the pixels are clipped if `z` value is smaller then `near` or larger then `far`. The border parameters are best computed with the field of view (angle) and screen aspect ratio. You use the tang function to compute border parameters to get the desired effect. This method is mostly used for 3D drawing.
- `LookAt` is a convenience which is used to transform all the objects to such positions and orientations that they appear to be effected by the camera position. Though this method is defined with vectors you may imagine it having a vector position and rotations. What this does it creates a matrix that will rotate all the objects by -rotations and translate them by -position.

Overall the usage then is pretty simple. Each position should first be multiplied by the model matrix which is the matrix representing the model position in your scene. Then multiplied by the matrix received with `lookAt` to simulate the camera. Then multiplied by the projection matrix which in most cases is either the `ortho` or the `frustum`. The optimization then is to multiply the matrices first on the CPU and then have the positions multiplied by them on the GPU. Some variations then persist where you split the matrix to the "model view matrix" and the "projection matrix". This is used to compute things like lighting effect where the position must not be effected by the projection matrix.

Comment: Best explanation camera ever.Thanks that explanation have so much to asimilate, I will do some differents test  when I arrive home ,I should fix my problem if i understand your explanation